# Using Protractor parameter value in plugin config in conf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, report

I would like my **protractor-screenshoter-plugin** to create report directory with spec name as directory name. Spec name is to be passed as parameter when running Protractor:
*protractor --specs **my_spec.js** conf.js*
After calling the above command I would like my test to be run and report to be created in directory **my_spec.js** (or my_spec).
Plugin's configuration is included in **conf.js**:

```
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-screenshoter-plugin',
    screenshotOnExpect: 'failure+success',
    screenshotOnSpec: 'failure',
    withLogs: false,
    htmlReport: true,
    screenshotPath: '',//I would like to put the --specs parameter value here
    writeReportFreq: 'end',
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true
}]
```

**Any ideas how to do it? How to access Protractor's '--specs' parameter value in conf.js?**

Comment: Can you try the below suggestion and let me know if that works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the CLI arguments passed when triggering Protractor using `process.argv` which will give you an array containing all the arguments

See the below extract from the Nodejs documentation on [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

> The process.argv property returns an array containing the command line
>   arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched. The first
>   element will be process.execPath. See process.argv0 if access to the
>   original value of argv[0] is needed. The second element will be the
>   path to the JavaScript file being executed. The remaining elements
>   will be any additional command line arguments.

When you execute `protractor conf.js --spec demo2.js`

The statement `console.log(process.argv)` in `conf.js` will output something like this below

```
[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\aditya\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\protractor',
  'conf.js',
  '--specs',
  'demo2.js' ]
```

Then build your logic to extract the value you need. In this specific case, to get the `specs` value (without extension, so that filename conflict does not occur), the below function would help

```
function getSpecsFromCLIArg() {
    for (i = 0; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
        if (process.argv[i] === '--specs') {
            var specFile = process.argv[i + 1];
            return specFile.substr(0, specFile.indexOf('.'));
        }
    }
}
console.log(getSpecsFromCLIArg())

plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-screenshoter-plugin',
    screenshotOnExpect: 'failure+success',
    screenshotOnSpec: 'failure',
    withLogs: false,
    htmlReport: true,
    screenshotPath: getSpecsFromCLIArg(),
    writeReportFreq: 'end',
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true
}]
```

Comment: Your resolution is fine, although I thought that maybe framework provides some easier way of getting that value. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: It is important to trim out the '.js' off the string - otherwise error occurs (which is obvious - file name and dir name cannot be identical).

Comment: yes, was lazy to add the logic to strip off .js :) Anyway approved your edit . Thanks!

Comment: You can access the command line args using `browser.params` in a protractor plugin